# Kotlin java.lang.NullPointerException: view.findViewById(R.id.textview) must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

java.lang.NullPointerException: view.findViewById(R.id.dni_r) must not be null
at com.example.tcenso21.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment.inicializar(DashboardFragment.kt:88)
at com.example.tcenso21.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onCreateView(DashboardFragment.kt:57)

Anyone can help me?
I'm trying to call a recyclerview inside a fragment from a nav button but im getting this error and the app crash when i press the button. What am I doing wrong?
I think has something to do with the conection between the adapter, the fragment and the inflated view of the recycler, but im out off ideas now.

Comment: Could you please post your XML and kotlin code related to recyclerview ?

Answer (score 1):

findViewById() returns a View if it exists.

Lifecycle of Fragment is little bit complicated and consist not only with OnCreateView, but also with OnViewCreated.
onViewCreated() runs after the View has been created, so you can bind them.
Android devs about that:

> The View objects in a Fragment, however, aren’t ready to be inflated
> until calling Fragment#onCreateView, so you need a way to defer
> property initialization for a View.
> [Source](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/common-patterns)

Try to move your recyclerview binding from OnCreateView to OnViewCreated
Something like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   var recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.dni_r)

}
```

Comment: Thanks this was one of my errores, the other one was cause I was binding the elements of the recyclerview inside the adapter and the fragment. Delete that binding of elements from the fragment and bind the rv inside the onviewcreated and works!! Thank you and thank you again for your time!